# Scoping difference between missing() and is.null()

Tags: r

I struggle to understand the scoping difference between `is.null` and `missing`, in particular why the following does not work for `is.null`, but works for `missing`:

```r
foo_iris <- function(a = NULL){
  if(!is.null(a)) return('not.null') else  return('is.null')
}

foo_iris(a = Species)
#> Error in foo_iris(a = Species): object 'Species' not found

foo_iris <- function(a = NULL){
  if(missing(a)) return('is.null') else return('not.null')
}

foo_iris(a = Species)
#> [1] "not.null"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not related to scoping.

R has lazy evaluation, which means arguments are only evaluated if/when necessary. `is.null` needs to evaluate `a` in order to check if it is a reference to the `NULL` object. This evaluation throws the error. `missing` does not evaluate `a`, see the documentation in `help("missing")`:

> This is a ‘special’ primitive function: it must not evaluate its
>   argument.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense

Comment: ... yet, this somehow *also is* related to scoping...??  Because  when I define a NULL object `Species<-NULL` in the global environment, the function works. Sorry, may have troubles to understand this on a fairly profound level

Comment: Well, that's just standard scoping. The explanation why the function using `missing` doesn't error is argument evaluation and not scoping. If you strongly believe the answer should involve scoping, I might be misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your code like as follows:

```
foo_iris <- function(a = NULL){
    if(exists(deparse(substitute(a))) && !is.null(a)) return('not.null') else  return('is.null')
}

foo_iris(a = Species)
```

Here `exists(deparse(substitute(a)))` checks for presence of the object. This along with lazy AND operator `&&` evaluates `is.null()`. Without lazy eval `is.null()` will fail due to absence of the object.

Comment: I think I prefer using `missing`, but this is very interesting nonetheless